# Password Protect sub domain laravel 5 install

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, password-protection

I have a Laravel install on a sub domain on my VPS. It's basically my development site to test and debug before I push it into production. My problem is that I can't seem to password protect the sub domain where it resides.

My currrent folder structure looks like this

```
public_html/laravel53
```

And my Sub domain points to the public folder in laravel

```
public_html/laravel53/public
```

I have tried setting up the password protection through cpanel with no avail on both the `laravel53` and `public` folders

This is my `.htaccess` file in the `public` folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>

Options -MultiViews

    </IfModule>


    RewriteEngine On

    DirectoryIndex index.php



    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


</IfModule>

AuthType Basic
AuthName "public"
AuthUserFile "/home/user/.htpasswds/public_html/laravel53/public/passwd"
require valid-user
```

And my `.htaccess` in `laravel53` folder

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "laravel53"
AuthUserFile "/home/user/.htpasswds/public_html/laravel53/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Neither of these seem to work with the auth stuff in them.I have created other test folders with password protection and they work so I think it has something to do with Laravel's htaccess or the pointing of my subdomian. Not sure what do from here

Comment: This question isn't Laravel specific at all, not sure why you tagged it as Laravel, but nevertheless, here's a possible solution if you still want to do it in Laravel, without touching your .htaccess file: https://github.com/olssonm/l5-very-basic-auth. I'd personally use that package and detect when you're in your specific environment to use it.

Comment: Hi Jean. I marked with laravel because I believe the reason htaccess won't work is because of how laravel is setup with it's htaccess. I'd prefer using htaccess as this wouldn't complicate my composer.json and moving the install from dev to production. Do I maybe just have the auth stuff in the wrong place in the htaccess?

Comment: Really can't tell, I never mess with the .htaccess files, sorry.